# C/C++ Determine Whether Files have been completely written

Tags: c++, file, eof

I have a directory (**DIR_A**) to dump from Server A to Server B which is
expected to take a few weeks. **DIR_A** has the normal tree
structure i.e. a directory could have subfolders or files, etc

**Aim:**
As **DIR_A** is being dumped to server B, I will have to
go through **DIR_A** and search for certain files within it (do not know the
exact name of each file because server A changes the names of all the files
being sent). I cannot wait for weeks to process some files within **DIR_A**. So, I want to
start manipulating some of the files once I receive them at server B.

**Brief:**
Server A sends **DIR_A** to Server B. Expected to take weeks.
I have to start processing the files at B before the upload is
complete.

***Attempt Idea:***
I decided to write a program that will list the contents of **DIR_A**.
I went on finding out whether files exist within folders and subfolders of **DIR_A**.
I thought that I might look for the EOF of a file within **DIR_A**. If it is not present
then the file has not yet been *completely* uploaded. I should wait till the EOF
is found. So, I keep looping, calculating the size of the file and verifying whether EOF is present. If this is the case, then I start processing that file.

To simulate the above, I decided to write and execute a program writing to
a text file and then stopped it in the middle without waiting for completion.
I tried to use the program below to determine whether the EOF could be found. I assumed that since I abrubtly ended the program writing to the text file the eof will not be present and hence the output "`EOF FOUND`" should not be reached. I am wrong since this was reached. I also tried with feof(), and fseek().

```
std::ifstream file(name_of_file.c_str, std::ios::binary);
//go to the end of the file to determine eof
char character;
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
while(!file.eof()){

    file.read(character, sizeof(char));

}
file.close();
std::cout << "EOF FOUND" << std::endl
```

Could anyone provide with an idea of determining whether a file has been completely written or not?

Comment: `eof` is not the right way to check for error. That should be `while(file.good())` or simply `while(file)`.

Comment: It is important to know how the files are being "sent", because depending on the method you may have different means of testing completeness.  Also, checking for eof will find the end of the file even if the file isn't completely written.  Probably better to use an (OS-level) call to figure out if anything else has the file open.

Comment: C tag is there because I also used the equivalent i.e. fseek and fopen(). Yes I have tried also if(file.bad()){file.close() return ""}

Answer (score 2):

EOF is simply C++'s way of telling you there is no more data. There's no EOF "character" that you can use to check if the file is completely written.

The way this is typically accomplished is to transfer the file over with one name, i.e. myfile.txt.transferring, and once the transfer is complete, move the file on the target host (back to something like myfile.txt). You could do the same by using separate directories.

Comment: Pedantically, there *is* an EOF character (Ctrl-D was standard, Windows used Ctrl-Z) but it was only ever used in text files and isn't even used anymore as far as I know.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: There is an ASCII "EOF" character, yes, but that's not what `std::istream::eof` is checking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Neither C nor C++ have a standard way to determine if the file is still open for writing by another process. We have a similar situation: a server that sends us files and we have to pick them up and handle as soon as possible. For that we use Linux's [`inotify`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) subsystem, with a watch configured for IN_CLOSE_WRITE events (file was closed after having been opened for writing), which is wrapped in boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor for convenient asynchronicity.

Depending on the OS, you may have a similar facility. Or just `lsof` as already suggested.

Comment: I will try to write a program using inotify hoping that I will not run into trouble with the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In C, and I think it's the same in C++, `EOF` is not a character; it is a condition a file is (or is not) in. Just like `media removed` or `network down` is not a character.

Answer (score 0):

All finite files have an end.  If a file is being written by one process, and (assuming the OS allows it) simultaneously read (faster than it is being written) by another process,then the reading process will see an EOF when it has read all the characters that have been written.

What would probably work better is, if you can determine a length of time during which you can guarantee that you'll receive a significant number of bytes and write them to a file (beware OS buffering), then you can walk the directory once per period, and any file that has changed its file size can be considered to be unfinished.

Another approach would require OS support: check what files are open by the receiving process, with a tool like `lsof`.  Any file open by the receiver is unfinished.

Comment: Yeps, I could verify the size of the file and test whether it is growing. But suppose the size stalls for some reason and then I verify and see that the size is still the same. I will then make the wrong assumption that the file is complete which might not be true.

Comment: Then you're stuck with the second solution: watch the process and see what files it has open.

Comment: Ok I will have to see if I could on Windows Server to watch whether the file is still open and is being written.

Comment: Perhaps, I could try with the c++ is_open() and determine if a file is already open

Comment: @user: No, that just tells you if the stream is associated with a file, not if another process has the file open.